# Multiple Excel Functions / Dealing with timeframes in a cell

Tags: excel, excel-formula, ms-office, formulas

Im trying to run multiple excel formulas in a cell in excel.

Currently i have:

> =IF(E2="off", "Not Scheduled", "")

What this does is if a cell shows "1" then another cell remains blank. If a cell shows "Off" then the other cell shows "Not Scheduled"

On top of that i want to include a formula that

> If G1 is less then or greater then D1 show "Missed Time Window"

So my questions:

How do i build multiple formulas into the same cell?
How do i tell excel that the data in cell D1 contains a timeframe? The data in cell D1 for example shows "14:00 - 16:00" so if G1 is less then or greater then the time set in D1 then show "Missed Time Window"

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`"14:00 - 16:00"` is not a time frame, at least not for Excel. Your "time frame" is really text. You may want to split that data into two columns, a start time and an end time. Let's assume start time is in D1 and end time in E1. Then your formula can look like

```
=if(and(G1>=D1,G1<=E1),"within time frame","Missed Time Window")
```

You can combine that with your first IF statement like this:

```
=IF(E2="off", "Not Scheduled", if(and(G1>=D1,G1<=E1),"within time frame","Missed Time Window"))
```